# when a variable of type Location is passed to "onLocationChanged". the App crashes

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

As shown below, why when i pass the `mCurrentLocation` which is retrieved from `getLastKnownLocation` to `onLocationChanged` callback, the app crashes?

JavaCode:

```
private void prepareGPS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mCriteria = new Criteria();
    setLocationProviderCriteria(this.mCriteria);
    this.mProvider = mLocMgr.getBestProvider(getLocationProviderCriteria(), false);
    if (this.mProvider == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), NO_PROVIDER, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        this.mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
        this.mCurrentLocation = this.mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        this.onLocationChanged(mCurrentLocation);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        this.latEt.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        this.lngEt.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLocationChanged returned NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.meetingpointlocator_03/com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.onLocationChanged(MeetingPointFix.java:163)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.prepareGPS(MeetingPointFix.java:155)
05-18 00:04:02.190: E/AndroidRuntime(9311):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.onCreate(MeetingPointFix.java:60)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.onLocationChanged(MeetingPointFix.java:163)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `this.onLocationChanged(mCurrentLocation);` before registering your listener `requestLocationUpdates`. I think, you are interrupting the callback after registering your listener.Also, please have a look on the [explanatory graph](http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbdd6da0a6fdfa462fe71/finding-current-location?tag=dragonfly), i think it might give an idea how these callbacks are working according to the precedences.

```
this.onLocationChanged(mCurrentLocation);
this.mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
this.mCurrentLocation = this.mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

onLocationChanged() is a callback, meaning it is event driven and should never be called explicitly. The OS calls it when it has got a positional fix. All methods called on...... are like this, I.e. callbacks. You have to wait to get a location fix and assume location will be null until the callback is invoked.